Copy timestamp and metadata from one file to another
I rotated an MP4-video and in this process lost the correct metadata and timestamp of the file.
Is there a way to copy the metadata and timestamp from the original (not roated) file to the new file. (Note, I am not asking how to copy a file preserving the timestamp, but rather how to transfer this information to another file.)

Check for exiftool

Check for exiftool
Batch copy metadata from one file to another (EXIFTOOL)
Copy of all metadata from one image file to another one
how can I copy custom exif fields from one image to another with exiftool?
Example:
exiftool -tagsfromfile orig.jpg -exif new.jpg
exiftool -tagsFromFile original.mp4 -all:all -P new.mp4
Get date from filename to change date in Meta Info of mp4 file with Exiftool
ExifTool command for batch copying .mp4 metadata from files to files?

The internal metadata in the file can be copied with something like exiftool.  (See other answer.)
You can copy the filesystem dates (atime, mtime) with touch -r oldfile newfile but ctime (change time) can only be set to the current time, it can't be changed otherwise.
There is probably not a tool to copy other filesystem metadata, you'd have to set it manually, and some can't be set by non-admin users.
